# Are there performance differences between views and in-line table functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm currently torn between a design decision between using a view and an in-line table function, where the argument in favor of the view is that it's a simple `SELECT`, but the argument for the table function is consistency, as we already have hundreds of objects in the database that do require parameters, and thus, use a table function.

Given that we have a table, `dbo.Data`, a view, `dbo.vData`, and an in-line table function, `dbo.tfData()`:

Our scenario is that we already have several table functions for the same table along the lines of `dbo.tfDataFilterBy(parameter)`, so having consistency when querying is a definite plus.  Performance is a significant factor in which direction we would go.

The new view and table function both just do a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.Data`.  I've tested some basic scenarios selects, joins, and aggregates and the execution plans are identical as far as I can tell.  However, are there any edge cases that can potentially produce a different execution plan between the two of them, perhaps with a lot of complex joins, sub-queries, or anything else we might throw at it?

Comment: A view and a table valued function are vastly different from each other. This is sort of like comparing tuna fish and watermelons. I would question why you want an inline table valued function that doesn't need a parameter to return the correct data. And if the query really is just a simple select....why bother with either?

Comment: @Lunyx . . . I would check to see if `where` clauses pick up underlying indexes.  If there are none, then I don't think you have as much to worry about.

Comment: @SeanLange The complexity is in which table to select from. To minimize locks and dirty reads when massive updates need to be made to the table, we create another copy and swap them out in the view/function.  And I've addressed why table functions are considered in the question itself.

Comment: Just because you use table valued functions for other things should have absolutely no bearing on this. You should use the construct that makes the most sense to the task at hand. Given the explanation of what you are doing it doesn't sound like it makes a lot of difference from a performance perspective either way.

Comment: @SeanLange I disagree.  To certain end users of our system that don't necessarily have a SQL background, but have very basic skills in writing simple queries, keeping things consistent definitely helps them.

Comment: Ummmm ok...why are end users writing sql??? If they don't possess the skills for writing queries they have no business in there. But whatever, it is your system.

Answer (score 0):

The two are defined in different manners, but the sql engine builds them from the base tables in much the same way.(Hence your execution plans being the same)

Keep in mind, views can in fact update the underlying base tables, so be careful with that difference.

See: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-view-basics/
for some good info on uses of views.

If you reuse a view a lot across your application(s), you could define it as an indexed view.  SQL server then materializes the view as a table.  This creates some overhead with maintaining the index when you make updates to your table, but the indexed view could improve read performance substantially.  Also, in Enterprise Edition, the optimizer can use the indexed view if it meets the requirements of a query even if it is not referenced directly.

An occasion in favor of table functions would be one where you need to change the definition of the table very slightly on a regular basis, you would not want to maintain multiple views that are so close in definition. Also, a table function can take a parameter that can be used in your predicates to change the output without changing the function, with views you would need different views defined with different predicates.

These are not the only differences, but are probably the two most influential when deciding which to use.

More directly related to performance:  there should not be much difference in execution plan UNLESS you utilize a view enough that the optimizer materializes the table from the definition.

Comment: Actually, the additional view/table function would not have a filter, so there would not be multiple to maintain.  Looks like I'll have a good article to read for the train ride home.  I didn't realize it would materialize the views if used often enough, but I'm not sure I can imagine it performing much differently especially if it was only a select straight from the table to begin with.  That seems like it could potentially be a downside by taking up more database space.

Comment: For sure, but if you are doing very simple queries you should be able to do them directly without much impact to your table performance.  Both of these other tools are for when you need to abstract out some complexity for repeated use.  You should also look into whether either or both of them handle locking, I suspect they can both be defined to do either dirty reads or committed only.

Comment: @user7396598 . . . I am not aware that SQL Server implements any sort of materialization of views based on how often they are executed.  Do you have any documentation reference for that?

Comment: It's in the article linked in the answer.  I was unaware until I read it as well.

Comment: @user7396598, Joe Celko did not say that Microsoft SQL Server materializes views as an optimization. He said "with a good optimizer, the SQL engine can decide that enough sessions are using the same VIEW and materialize it as a shared table". That statement is speaking of theory rather than reality as he's been isolated in an ivory tower for decades :-)

Comment: @user7396598 The complexity is actually in which table to select from.  To minimize locks and dirty reads when massive updates need to be made to the table, we create another copy and swap them out in the view/function.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, well that is disappointing.  I'll update the answer to reflect how an indexed view could be helpful, but that you have to manually define it.